# Understanding and fixing this error Message when using BOOST_DLL_ALIAS

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to create plugins using boost and am having some difficulty getting it to work, I am following [this tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_dll/tutorial.html#boost_dll.tutorial.plugin_basics) from boost.org.
I am using boost 1_70 compiled with Visual Studio 2015.
This is my code for the interface IFoo.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/config.hpp>
//Pluggin Interface for Puffs
class BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE IFoo {
    public:
    //returns size of Foo
    virtual size_t Size() = 0;
    //get single byte from foo
    virtual unsigned char getByte(unsigned long loc) = 0;
};
```

This is my code for Foo.h:

```
#include <boost/dll/alias.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp> 
#include "IFoo.h"

namespace someSpace{
class Foo: public IFoo
{
    size_t FooSize;
    unsigned char * someData;
    Foo(std::string someString);
public:
    ~Foo();
    size_t Size();
    unsigned char getByte(unsigned long byteLoc);

    //Factory method
    static boost::shared_ptr<IFoo> create(std::string fooName);
};

BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(
    someSpace::Foo::create, //<-- this function is exported with...
    load_foo                 //<-- this alias
)
}
```

And here is the code for foo.cpp if it is needed:

```
#include "Foo.h"
namespace someSpace {
     Foo::Foo()std::string fooData)
     {
         strcpy(someData, fooData.c_str());
     }
     size_t Foo::size()
     {
         return FooSize;
     }
     unsigned char Foo::getByte(unsigned long byteLoc)
     {
          return someData[byteLoc % FooSize); 
     }

     static boost::shared_ptr<IFoo> Foo::create(std::string fooName)
     {
          return boost::shared_ptr<IFoo> ( new Foo(fooName) );
     }
}
```

I am getting an error from BOOST_DLL_ALIAS() which reads

> #define BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(FunctionOrVar, AliasName) this declaration has no storage class or type specifier

Why am I getting this message from boost and how can I fix it?

Comment: `someSpace::Foo` doesn't contain a function called `create`

Comment: create is a static method for class Foo, doesn't that mean that create is a function someSpace::Foo?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and will not compile as-is (for starters, `IFoo` is not declared -- and is inheritance needed in this case?). When I added placeholders to make it complete enough to compile, I did not get the message you mentioned. I conclude that you have not provided enough information. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I modified it, giving more data. IFoo is an interface, as this is for creating a DLL, IFoo is the interface that tells other programs how to interact with the module when they are using it. This is following the way the boost tutorial did it.

Answer (score 0):

Just move it outside the namespace, it seems not to work with demangling:

```
#include <boost/dll/alias.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp> 
#include "IFoo.h"

namespace someSpace{
class Foo: public IFoo
{
    size_t FooSize;
    unsigned char * someData;
    Foo(std::string someString);
public:
    ~Foo();
    size_t Size();
    unsigned char getByte(unsigned long byteLoc);

    //Factory method
    static boost::shared_ptr<IFoo> create(std::string fooName);
};
}

BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(
    someSpace::Foo::create, //<-- this function is exported with...
    load_foo                 //<-- this alias
)
```